# When I input any char inside int it makes it equal 8

Tags: c

im facing a problem in part of my code, where i have switch(num) and have cases for numbers from 6 to 14 and default . whenever the input is not an integer the switch statement reads it as 8 and not as default and when i removed 8 it went back to default !

any ideas why is this happening ?

Thank you in advance

example of my problem

```
scanf("%d",&num);
switch(num) 
{ case 6 : loop6 ; break; 
case 7 :  loop7 ; break;
case 8 :  loop8 ; break ; 
default : printf("unknow value "); break ; }
```

input : not an integer 
output : enters loop8 and doesnt print unknow value .

Comment: Did you want us to guess?

Comment: Are you switching on integers or `char *`s? It will only work for integers.

Comment: here guys what is happening to me i hope it makes it clearer . @dour high arch

Comment: switching on integers still doesnt work ... @Joe

Comment: IIRC, if you input "not a number", it's implementation-defined whether `num` would actually be modified in any way. So, it might still contain the previous value, or it might have complete garbage in it...

Comment: What are `loop6`, `loop7`, and `loop8`? If they're functions the code you've shown us doesn't call them (function calls require parentheses). You *really* need to read http://sscce.org/

Comment: @twalberg: I don't believe it's implementation-defined; as far as I can tell, in the event of a matching failure the variable isn't updated. But that raises a good point: the code should *definitely* be checking the value returned by `scanf`.

Comment: @twalberg your answer makes sense ! Thanks

Comment: @KeithThompson You could be right... I don't have a copy of the standard handy to look at. Not sure if it's actually dictated by the standard, or if it's just common practice...

Comment: @twalberg nailed it thank you !

Comment: @twalberg: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is the most recent public draft; `fscanf` is described in section 7.21.6.2. I don't think it actually says what happens to the addressed object on a matching failure, which makes me think that it leaves it alone.

Comment: It appears that there probably is enough information in the question to make a good guess at what the problem is, and @twalberg's comment is a good one (the problem is that `num` kept its earlier value). But I *still* strongly urge you to replace the code in the question with a complete self-contained program that illustrates the problem. If nothing else, it would be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your variable `num` already had a value in it.

When you enter a non-numerical value, `scanf` fails and does not update `num`. It will therefore still be whatever it was before; in your case, it was apparently 8.

If I am right, the following should fix it for you:

```
int num = -1;
if(scanf("%d",&num)==1) {
  switch(num) 
  { 
  case 6 : 
    loop6() ; 
    break; 
  case 7 :  
    loop7() ; 
    break;
  case 8 :
    loop8() ; 
    break ; 
  default : 
    printf("unknown value: %d \n", num);
    break;
  }
}
```

Note - `scanf` returns the number of arguments successfully converted; testing the return value is robust to input errors. If input conversion failed, it makes no sense to go through the `switch` statement. Assigning an (invalid) value to `num` before `scanf` is another way to make sure that this problem will not happen.